# Creating global variable named by argument of a method

Tags: python-3.x, methods, dictionary, global

I am working on a project in Python3.2 for which I need to create a dictionary and assign keys and values read out of a textfile automatically.
The most part is done:

```
def loadDict(file,dictname):
    with open(file,"r") as dict_file:
            for i in range(sum(1 for line in open(file))):
                    line = dict_file.readline()
                    part0,part1 = "", ""
                    part0 = line.split("\:/")[0][1:(len(line.split("\:/")[0])-1)]
                    part1 = line.split("\:/")[1][1:(len(line.split("\:/")[1])-1)]
                    dictname[part0] = part1
            dict_file.close()
```

I can use it by creating a dictionary and call the function respectively:

```
test_dictinary = {}
loadDict("my_file","test_dictionary")
print(test_dictionary)
```

by getting proper results. The problem for me is: I need to create an empty dictionary before calling the method on it.

I wounder if there was a way to create a global dictionary within that method on its own. So that

```
loadDict("my_file","test_dictionary")
```

will automatically create the dictionary "test_dictionary" for me which I can use in other methods.
I've also tried it with fromdict with the same result.
Searchfunction here and google did not give me any solutions (except fromdict which did not work).

EDIT[Solution by community]:

```
def loadDict(file,dictname):
helpdict = {}
with open(file,"r") as dict_file:
        for line in dict_file:
                part0 = line.split("\:/")[0][1:(len(line.split("\:/")[0])-1)]
                part1 = line.split("\:/")[1][1:(len(line.split("\:/")[1])-1)]
                helpdict[part0] = part1
        globals()[dictname] = helpdict
```

Comment: The purpose of opening a file using a `with` statement is so the `with` handles closing it for you. Closing it yourself is redundant.

Comment: `for i in range(sum(1 for line in open(file))): line = dict_file.readline()` - why would you do that? You open the file a second time, without closing it, just to figure out how many lines there are to read. Why not just use `for line in dict_file`?

Comment: @user2357112 Not exactly part of the original question. I tend to overcomplicate things when I set up something and clean it up afterwards. No excuse for bad code, but the reason you asked for. Thank you for helping me on that part. Problem solved and code cleaned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very bad way of coding, why not just return the created dict? If you really want to programmatically create global variables I guess you can use the `globals` function:

```
def fun():
  globals()['a'] = 1

>> fun() 
>> a
1
```

Comment: Thanks, the globals() function was what I did not find in approximately 3 hours of research. And the bad code.. was an attempt to get it running globally. Except there's no excuse for bad code.